# C Logging Function

Tags: c, file, logging

I wrote this log function and it works but is there a better way to write into the file stream and console at the same time?

````
//The function
void log(int lvl, const char * format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    //If lvl < 0 the prefix will not be used
    if (lvl>=lINFO) {
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        struct tm tm = *localtime(&now);

        //Printing to the console
        printf("[%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d %s] [%s] : ",
             tm.tm_year+1900,
             tm.tm_mon+1,
             tm.tm_mday,
             tm.tm_hour,
             tm.tm_min,
             tm.tm_sec,
             __log_name,
             parse_lvl(lvl)
        );

        //Printing into the file
        //Checking if NULL(if yes the file wont be used)
        if(__log_filestream)
            fprintf(__log_filestream,
                "[%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d %s] [%s] : ",
                 tm.tm_year+1900,
                 tm.tm_mon+1,
                 tm.tm_mday,
                 tm.tm_hour,
                 tm.tm_min,
                 tm.tm_sec,
                 __log_name,
                 parse_lvl(lvl)
            );
    }
    //Printing to the console
    vprintf(format, args);
    printf("\n");

    //Printing into the file
    if (__log_filestream) {
        vfprintf(__log_filestream, format, args);
        fprintf(__log_filestream, "\n");
    }
    va_end(args);
}

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing `printf` and `fprintf` *twice* for the same arguments.

So, it's replicating code.

`*printf` is somewhat heavyweight. So, I'd do `sprintf` [or `snprintf`] to a buffer (e.g):

```
len = sprintf(buf,...);
```

And then do:

```
fwrite(buf,1,len,stdout);
if (__log_filestream)
    fwrite(buf,1,len,__log_filestream);
```

The overhead of using the buffer is less than calling a `printf` function twice. I'd repeat the same buffering for the `vprintf/vfprintf`

---

Or, better yet, just keep concatenating to the buffer and do a single [pair of] `fwrite` at the end. This is [yet] better performance.

And, this is especially helpful if there are multiple threads doing logging because the given log message will come out on a single line (e.g.):

```
threadA timestamp | threadA message
threadB timestamp | threadB message
```

With two separate writes to a stream, two threads could intersperse partial parts of their message [not nearly as nice]:

```
threadA timestamp
threadB timestamp
threadA message
threadB message
```

Note that this is enough to guarantee that we see nice/whole lines. But, it doesn't prevent a race for the ordering of two lines for each stream. That is, we could have [on `stdout`]:

```
threadA line
threadB line
```

But, it might not prevent [on the logfile stream]:

```
threadB line
threadA line
```

So, we could wrap the `fwrite` calls in a mutex. Or, we could just wrap the calls in a `flockfile(stdout)` / `funlockfile(stdout)` pairing (See: `FORCE_SEQUENTIAL` in the example below)

---

If this function is the *only* function writing to the logfile and/or `stdout`, you might get even better performance by using `write` instead of `fwrite` [YMMV]

---

Here's how I would refactor the code [and, if you're paranoid, you could use `snprintf`]:

```
// The function
void
log(int lvl,const char *format,...)
{
    va_list args;
    char buf[1000];
    char *cur = buf;

    // If lvl < 0 the prefix will not be used
    if (lvl >= lINFO) {
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        struct tm tm;
        localtime_r(&now,&tm);

        // Printing to the console
        cur += sprintf(cur,"[%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d %s] [%s] : ",
            tm.tm_year + 1900,tm.tm_mon + 1,tm.tm_mday,
            tm.tm_hour,tm.tm_min,tm.tm_sec,
            __log_name,parse_lvl(lvl));
    }

    va_start(args, format);
    cur += sprintf(cur,format,args);
    va_end(args);

    *cur++ = '\n';
    *cur = 0;

    size_t len = cur - buf;

    // lock [either] stream to force both streams to come out "atomically" in
    // the same order
#ifdef FORCE_SEQUENTIAL
    flockfile(stdout);
#endif

    // Printing to the console
    fwrite(buf,1,len,stdout);

    // Printing into the file
    if (__log_filestream)
        fwrite(buf,1,len,__log_filestream);

#ifdef FORCE_SEQUENTIAL
    funlockfile(stdout);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## API

You only provide one function, but it seems worthwhile documenting the expectations:

- `log(level, format, ...)`
- `level` appears to expect a set of pre-defined values, notably `lINFO`. Is there an enum somewhere? Should the type of `level` by an enum typedef?
- `format` should not include a trailing newline

## Implementation

### Comments

Your comments seem to indicate the code you wish you had written. Perhaps you should trust your instincts?

In general, comments that describe what is happening are bad comments: the *code* describes what is happening! These types of comments only serve to drift slowly out of date, forgetting to mention things that are added later. Eventually, they turn into a sort of dotty grandmother, who remembers what you were like at version 1, but doesn't remember that you're integrated with another package now, with one major plugin already and a new one on the way...

Instead, write comments to draw attention to things that might be non-obvious, or to highlight negative information (Negative as in "the dog that didn't bark", like the `default` in a switch statement except at a higher level).

### Organization

I meant it when I said you should trust your instincts! If you're writing a comment to give a name to more than one line of code, maybe that code is a function.

(And dundernames*, like `__log_filestream`, are reserved. Don't use them.)

```
void log ... etc ...
{
    if (level >= lINFO) {
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        struct tm tm = *localtime(&now);

        log_prefix_to_stream(stdout, lvl, &tm);
        log_prefix_to_stream(log_filestream, lvl, &tm);
    }

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    log_vprint_to_stream(lvl, format, args, stdout);
    log_vprint_to_stream(lvl, format, args, log_filestream);

    va_end(args);
}
```

And seeing that refactoring puts two things in my head: first, that the prefix should probably be a function by itself, and second that the doubled printing lines could probably go into a single function, if only we were smart enough!

Something like this:

```
void log ... etc ...
{
    if (lvl >= lINFO) 
        log_prefix(lvl);

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    log_vprintf(format, args);
    log_append_newline();

    va_end(args);
}
```

Which then leads to `log_prefix` wanting to call `log_vprint`, but needing an intermediate function to make a va_list:

```
void log_printf(format, ...);
```

Which might call `log_vprintf`, in the interest of DRY, and we've found the missing `if` statement(s)!

```
void log_vprintf(format, args)
{
    if (log_filestream != NULL)
        vfprintf(log_filestream, format, args);
    vfprintf(stdout, format, args);
}
```

=====

(*): "dundernames" are **d**ouble-**under**score-**names** -- that is, names that start with '__'

Answer (score 2):

**Time detail**

When the clock goes from daylight savings time to standard time, the below code can print the same time that was reported one hour earlier.

```
//Printing to the console
printf("[%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d %s] [%s] : ",
     tm.tm_year+1900,
     tm.tm_mon+1,
     tm.tm_mday,
     tm.tm_hour,
     tm.tm_min,
     tm.tm_sec,
     __log_name,
     parse_lvl(lvl)
);
```

To help distinguish times, consider printing `tm.tm_isdst`.

Alternatively, research `strftime()` and [IS0 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```
char buf[100];
strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%FT%T%Z", &tm);
printf("[%s %s] [%s] : ", buf, __log_name, parse_lvl(lvl));
```

---

Or use UTC and skip timezones

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm tm = *gmtime(&now);
char buf[100];
strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%FT%TZ", &tm);
printf("[%s %s] [%s] : ", buf, __log_name, parse_lvl(lvl));
```